# How to Redirect Non WWW Website to WWW Version on Unmanager Server?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have hosted my Website on Digital Ocean & Installed Wordpress through Serverpilot. Current Home Page URL is www.xyz.com & xyz.com is also redirecting on it.

But When I open xyz.com/test-post its not rediecting on www.xyz.com/test-post. How can I Redirect it ?

Answer (score 0):

> Set the `www` version of URL in **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address
>   (URL)**  fields present under WordPress (backend)  [image: *Settings > General*]

and then write this in your `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for Your Help. I have tried this one. But Still xyz.com/post-name is not redirecting to www.xyz.com/post-name

Comment: after doing the above thing, try this: change your _Permalink Settings_ to **Plain** and then again to **Post name**. this should fixed your issue.