# non www to www for both http and https not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Have searched and applied many of the rewrite rules available but no avail,

I am trying

http://website.io/paypal should go http://www.website.io/paypal
but it simply goes to www home page http://www.website.io

should be the same for https. Or at lest non-www redirects to https://www.website.io/paypal is fine, but should carry the page name.

after many trial and error versions here is the closest one I have got which isn't working good

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# WordPress Defaults
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

***UPDATE***

It seems nothing wrong with redirection though, www and non www domains were mapped to different ips thus not found on non-www urls.

Comment: You can define this in wordpress admin paneld -> Settings -> Common. Yo u don't need to set this in `.htaccess`

Comment: have you set your home and site url as www version ? check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41198097/5019802

Comment: Works pretty well on a standard apache installation.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out @sepher, you were right, nothing wrong with redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your exact working code. This will redirect you to your desired page perfectly.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}paypal [R=301,L]

# WordPress Defaults
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Note: Only this below line has some minor change otherwise you have done great job.

```
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}paypal [R=301,L]
```

Let me know if it solves your issue ?

Comment: adding this above code will take you to www.website.io/paypal  that's what is equal to http://www.website.io/paypal now what's issue ?

Comment: What about `www.website.io/foo` or `www.website.io/bar`? `%{REQUEST_URI}` takes care of whatever comes after the host, no matter it's `paypal`, `foo` or `bar`. The real question is why it's not working on OP's machine. Or why `%{REQUEST_URI}` is empty?

Comment: it should not be empty at all ... then contact with your server administrator

Comment: got it fixed from server admin @Akramulhaq, was a DNS mapping issue. thanks